# Change a cell number in formula from another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Basically I have this formula:

```
=(MIKE!$B8)
```

and I have a bunch of cells withs Numbers like so:

```
Cell | Cell Number Change
C1 | 10 
C2 | 16
C3 | 29
C4 | 40
C5 | 61
```

What I want to do is to be able to change the number "8" for the formula by referencing a cell to grab a number, which will thus change the formula and the output of the data. I'll use it to copy and paste down and change the numbers out to get only the output of different cells that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use the `INDIRECT` function:

```
=INDIRECT("MIKE!$B" & C1)
```

This would take the number from C1 (In your example, 10) and use this in the lookup, returning the value in `MIKE!$B10`.

[image]

Comment: I believe this will work, but im getting a ref error.
=INDIRECT("MIKE!$B" & "MIKE!$C10") The number is coming from MIKE sheet as well

Comment: Fixed it: =INDIRECT("MIKE!$B" & (MIKE!$N8))  had to wrap it in (), thanks for the assistance it worked perfectly.